# Need HTML Code to read text from webpage and use it as a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a webpage that will open when I push a button, perform its function, then self close.  The function is to interpret the state of a relay and toggle it from on to off or from off to on.

**Brief Background:**

I am toggling relays that are on a web-enabled board. There are 16 relays on each board. Each relay is toggled by opening a specific webpage. for example: 192.168.1.4/30000/05 turns on relay 3. 192.168.1.4/30000/06 turns it off.

I can get the status of all 16 relays on the board by opening 192.168.1.4/30000/99.  When I do this, it returns a webpage with a 16 digit binary response. The leftmost digit represents relay 1 status (1=off, 0=on) and the rightmost digit is relay 16.  for example: 1001100111001101

**The Request:**

I need help with code that will open the ...99 website (which I can already do), interpret the status of a specific relay (say relay 3), set that status to a variable and use that variable in an if/else statement which will open the appropriate webpage to toggle the relay.

I have no idea how to extract data from the open ...99 website and to parse it to the specific relay status that I am trying to target.

Here is the code I have so far.  I'm having a bit of trouble getting it to load correctly on this page.  And, yes.  I am a VERY novice coder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <title>Button Press</title>


<--This script opens a window which displays the status of 16 relays in binary fashion. It closes the "data" window and then closes the browser.  For example: 1100001000110011 means relays 1,2,7,11,12,15,16 are on. Others are off. -->

  <script type="text/javascript">

    function GetStatus(){

     var win = window.open('http://192.168.0.89/30000/99');


      setTimeout(function() {win.close();}, 1000);

      var closeme = window.open('', '_self', '');;

      setTimeout(function() {closeme.close();}, 4000);

        }

  </script>

<--Here I need help with code that will interpret the data extracted above and singling out a single relay for use as a variable (Status) with the if/else statement below. For example, I want to know the status of relay 3 from GetStatus and set it as the varible to use below.-->


<--This if/else statement is intended to use the relay Status variable collected above and open one of two webpages to trigger the relay to go to the alternate state. The relays are toggled by opening a specific webpage.  192...05 turns it on, 192... 04 turns it off.  The page will open, then close after a timeout.  I hope I have designed my if/else statement correctly.  I have assumed Status is a variable created by the parsing process commented above (that I have no idea how to do) -->

if(Status = 0) {
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function ActionOff(){

     var win = window.open('http://192.168.0.89/30000/05','','');


      setTimeout(function() { win.close();}, 1000);

    }

  </script>

} else {

  <script type="text/javascript">

    function ActionOn(){
     var win = window.open('http://192.168.0.89/30000/06','','');


     SetTimeout(function() { win.close();}, 1000);

    }

  </script>
}


    </head>


<--The intention is for this page to automate upon opening, then close itself when it is done via the GetStatus function.-->

    <body onload="GetStatus();">

    </body>


</html>
```

If everything has worked correctly, when I go to this webpage, it will open, read the status of all relays, isolate the target relay status, and via the if/else statement, toggle the status of the relay from on to off, or from off to on.  Then all windows and the browser will close.

Comment: In order to capture the data corresponding to the status of the relays, we need to see the code from the "data" window that opens. Your `GetStatus` function doesn't return any value presently.

Comment: @sgt aj    I used view source to see the code behind the data page.  `<small><a href="http://192.168.089/30000"></a></small><a href="http://192.168.089/30000/1101111111111111">1101111111111111</a><p>` The GetStatus function simply opens the webpage. I just don't know what to do with it.

Comment: I didn't sent you the comment. @SgtAJ did

Comment: I'm a little unclear on exactly what you want to do here.  When you say you want the webpage to read the status of all relays and isolate the target relay and toggle it, how are you selecting which is the target relay?  I'm not sure how to intercept the response from the GetStatus function, unless you have some documentation from your board that tells you, or you can find something on google.  What board are you using?

Comment: The website 1...99 has the source code in the earlier comment.  The 1s and 0s represent the state of each relay. I'm not sure there is any value in opening this page as opposed to calling/getting the source code when I run the GetStatus function.  I need the 91st character. It is the relay status I am targeting.  I need a script that will get the 91st character from the source code of 1...99 and use that character (either a 1 or a 0) as the variable in if/else statement. This statement, in turn, opens one of two websites 1...5 or 1...6 causing the relay to toggle. @Sgt AJ

Comment: As I think about this, I could accomplish this via app or script, if it is easier. I just need something that will open and scrape website 1...99 for character 91 in the source code, use that character for an if/else statement, then  open and close one of two websites as result of the if/else statement. @Sgt AJ

Comment: The problem is how to scrape the webpage if you can't open it manually since it is only opened by the GetStatus function.  If you were to make an AJAX call to 3000/99, I wonder if the resulting webpage would be returned to the AJAX function as a response.

Comment: Tried running the sample code `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.get("http://192.168.0.89/30000/99", function(data, status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send an HTTP GET request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>
</html>`

Comment: produces this error is firefox: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.0.89/30000/99. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Comment: and this error in ms edge: SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd.

Comment: but if I change the target website to the generic weather page for msn, it works without a problem.  Not sure how to correct the issue. But, I'm thinking if it does work, I could use the script to load a variable to use in an if/else statement.